# Parallel RL-Circuit with non-sinusoidal current source

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, inductance

Consider a parallel RL-circuit, connected to a current source $I(t)$. The signal is for the moment arbitrary, so **not** sinusoidal.

[image: Parallel RL-Circuit]

> QUESTION 1: Find the differential equation of the voltage $U(t)$.

In the case of a RL (or RLC) circuit *in series* one would write:
$$
U(t) = \frac{1}{C}\int{I(t)dt}+L\frac{dI(t)}{dt}+RI(t)
$$
*In parallel* - in our case - one can write:
$$
I(t) = \frac{1}{R}U(t)+\frac{1}{L}\int{U(t)dt}
$$
but I don't know how to express $U(t)$.

> QUESTION 2: Calculate $U(t)$ for
>
> $$
> I(t) = \begin{cases} 
>       0 & t<0\\
>       I_0 & t\geq 0\\
>    \end{cases}
> $$

How would I approach these two questions?

Comment: Hint:  take the time derivative of your second equation to answer question 1

Comment: Thanks. Do you have another hint? My result doesn't seem right.

Comment: Josephus, think about it:  the inductor current is continuous so, at $t=0+$, *all* of the current is through the resistor thus $U(0+) = I_0R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Alfreds hint for Q1:
$$
U(t) = L\frac{dI(t)}{dt}-\frac{L}{R}\frac{dU(t)}{dt}
$$
For Q2:
$$
U(t) = L\frac{d}{dt}\left(I_0 \Theta(t)\right)-\frac{L}{R}\frac{dU(t)}{dt}
= LI_0 \delta(t)-\frac{L}{R}\frac{dU(t)}{dt}
$$
Solving the differential equation:
$$
U(t) = C_1 e^{-\frac{Rt}{L}}+I_0 R \Theta(t) e^{-\frac{Rt}{L}}
$$
with an unknown constant $C_1$.

The current through an inductor $L$ must always be continuous, otherwise it would defy the conservation of energy. Because $I(t)$ is discontinuous at $t=0$, the "jump" of current flows solely through the resistor $R$. So we see:
$$
U(t=0) = RI_0
$$
It then follows that $C_1=0$ and
$$
U(t) = I_0 R \Theta(t) e^{-\frac{Rt}{L}}
$$

**Why it makes sense**: The voltage of an inductor $U_L=L\frac{dI}{dt}$ is dependend on the change of current. With no change for a long time ($t\rightarrow \infty$) $U_L=0$, the inductor is a short circuit.